# Javascript selecbox.options to array?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

From what I understand a `option` elements that popuate `select` elements in HTML are an array.
So basically what i want to do is return an array string that is separated by commas.

Tried to do `selecbox.options.join(',');`, but got an error that its not supported; anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You want to return an array of elements converted to a string, separated by comma -- this makes no sense. It'll basically be `[object HTMLOptionElement], [object HTMLOptionElement]` do you mean you want the values of each option separated by comma, or convert an array-like object to a simple array?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not an array. It is an HTMLCollection. It is "array-like"

In 2022, a week before EOL of Internet Explorer 11, the simplest vanilla JavaScript solution is using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

UPDATE: [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is actually preferable to the spread since it is more obvious what is going on

```js
const opts = document.querySelectorAll("select option"); 
// we can use forEach on the resulting HTMLCollection 
// but map needs to be spread to array
const vals = Array.from(opts) // or [...opts]
  .map(el => el.value); 
console.log(vals);
```

```html
<select>
<option value="Please select">Text 0</option>
<option value="one">Text 1</option>
<option value="two">Text 2</option>
<option value="three">Text 3</option>
</select><br/> 
The above select has the following option values:<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

---

**Older answer that is compatible with IE11**

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ which CAN iterate over either:

> Iterate over both objects and arrays.
> Arrays and array-like objects with a
> length property (such as a function's
> arguments object) are iterated by
> numeric index, from 0 to length-1.
> Other objects are iterated via their
> named properties.

Each [HTML Option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) has a value and a text and some more attributes.

A simple for loop can be used

```
vals = []
var sel = document.querySelector("select");
for (var i=0, n=sel.options.length;i<n;i++) { // looping over the options
  if (sel.options[i].value) vals.push(sel.options[i].value);
}
```

the [Array.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) posted by typeracer will return an array of HTMLOptionElements which still needs to be looped over or mapped to get at the values and texts

Here are a few versions that will return the same.

[This fiddle will run in IE11 too](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nwmzsghc/show)

```js
var vals, sel = document.querySelector("select"), show=function(vals) {$("#result").append("[" + vals.join("][") + "]<hr/>");}
var supportsES6 = function() {try{new Function("(a = 0) => a");return true;}catch (err) {return false;  }}();


// jQuery mapping jQuery objects - note the "this" and the .get()
vals = $('select > option').map(function() {return this.value;}).get();
show(vals);

// plain JS using loop over select options
vals = [];
for (var i = 0, n = sel.options.length; i < n; i++) { // looping over the options
  if (sel.options[i].value) vals.push(sel.options[i].value); // a bit of testing never hurts
}
show(vals);

// Plain JS using map of HTMLOptionElements - note the el
vals = Array.apply(null, sel.options).map(function(el) { return el.value; });
show(vals);

// ES6 JS using spread and map of HTMLOptionElements - note the fat arrow and el
if (supportsES6) 
  document.write(`<script>

  vals = [...sel.options].map(el => el.value);

show(vals);
<\/script>`
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="Please select">Text 0</option>
<option value="one">Text 1</option>
<option value="two">Text 2</option>
<option value="three">Text 3</option>
</select><br/> 
The above select has the following option values:<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: as far as i know it is an options array ( otherwise how come we can access items by index? like selectbox.options[1] ?)
what i need it to take all values ( not just selected values ),
connect them with commas and return the result.

Comment: "The options property is an array of all the options in a particular Select object. There is one element (numbered in ascending order from zero) for each <OPTION> tag."

Comment: ok, so from your edit i understand the selecbox.options is actually an object array, and not an regular array. is that right ?

Comment: A shorter version of the apply variant is `Array.apply(null, sel.options).map(el => el.value)` by using array functions and the shorter return

Answer (score 30):

The most concise solution is this:

```
Array.apply(null, selectbox.options)
```

`Array.apply` calls the `Array` constructor with the first argument as the context (i.e. `this`) and the second argument which is any array-like object ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)).

We pass `null` for the first argument because we're not trying to call a method on a specific object, but rather a global constructor.

So in general,

```
Array.apply(null, A)
```

Will create a proper array containing the elements of any "array-like" object `A`.

Comment: MDN currently [isn't very helpful with browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Browser_compatibility), but with some quick testing on Chrome, FF, and IE, it seems Modern Browser Friendly (c) 2016. Very nice answer.

Comment: And to get the text of those options only: Array.apply(null, selextbox.options).map(function(el){return el.text;});

Comment: NOTE: `Array.apply(null, document.querySelector("select").options)` will still produce `[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement]`  - so additional mapping or looping is needed to get values and texts

Answer (score 7):

To get all the values into an array:

```
var options = document.getElementById('selectId').options;
var values = [];
var i = 0, len = options.length;

while (i < len)
{
  values.push(options[i++].value);
}
alert(values.join(', '));
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/64pyb/1/

---

> wow a long way to do something short

Well you can use a for loop, not much shorter but more ugly;

```
for (var options = document.getElementById('selectId').options,
          values, i = 0, len = options.length; i < len;i++)
  values.push(options[i].value);

alert(values.join(', '));
```

Then again it's a shame you're not using a library like jQuery. You could do:

```
$('select > option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Answer (score 7):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) makes it really easy (`[ ...ElementList ]`).


So for your case you can do the following:

`arr = document.getElementById('store-locator-region')`


Then convert the html select element to an object array using the spread operator:

`newArr = [...arr]`


And then iterate over your object array to get your final array:

`countryList = newArr.map(a => a.value)`
`(97) ["XE", "AL", "DZ", "AD", "AR", "AM", etc..]`

Comment: deserves more fame!

Answer (score 5):

`selecbox.options` is a collection (`nodeList`). You can iterate over its elements like you do with an array and push the members of the collection to a real array.

For the record: in all browsers but IE<9 you can use `[].slice.call(selecbox.options);`<sup>**1**</sup> to quickly convert a collection to an array.

So a crossbrowser way to convert a nodeList collection to array would be:

```
function coll2array(coll){
    var ret = [];
    try {
       ret = [].slice.call(coll)
    }
    catch(e) {
        for (var i =0;i<coll.length;i++){
            ret.push(coll[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

[**edit**] Nowadays (ES2015 and up) we can use `Array.from(options)` or `[...options]`.

<sup>**1**</sup> or `Array.prototype.slice.call([some collection])`

Comment: thx for the info, but as best practice i prefer a CrossBrowser solution.

Comment: Also you still need to process this new array of HTMLOptionElement object

Answer (score 2):

select.options is not an array, it is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) which shares some of the features of an array and so can be described as array like. a NodeList doesn't have the methods that an Array has, but you can [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) those methods to it.
In your case you can call the join method like this:

```
var opts = yourSelect.options;
var str = Array.prototype.join.call( opts, ',' );
```

Alternatively you could convert the NodeList into a true Array with a similar technique

```
// slice returns a new array, which is what we want
var optsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( opts );
```

Comment: However that returns `[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement],[object HTMLOptionElement]`

Comment: @mplungjan - true, [object HTMLOptionElement] is the result of a call to Option.toString(). So using this answer as a solution is pretty useless. My answer does explain the Why? part of the OP's question tho

Answer (score 1):

You can join an array of strings, but an option is not a string, it's an object with all kinds of properties like value and text. Which should it use to join?

You just have to write a loop to append all values you want.

Or use a library and use some each() function to loop through the options.

Comment: use a library ? for this function ? add 65k to my project for a simple thing ?
thats a bad advice.

Comment: I meant only when you're already using a library. I just wanted to make the options clear.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why no one suggested this:

```js
$(selecbox).find("option").map((index, option) => {
  // do stuff
});
```