# Where can I find documentation for this weird behavior of `Element.querySelector`

Tags: javascript

While debugging a validation routine, I ran across this odd behavior with  `Element.querySelector` where I pass a selector to it that should target `select` elements and it returned, not just one, but **every** `option` element that is child of the targeted `select`.

Example:

```js
(() => {
  const handlerWeird = (e) => {
    const select = Array.from(document.querySelector('#i-am-a-select'));
    console.log(select);
  };
  const handlerNormal = (e) => {
    const select = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#i-am-a-select'));
    console.log(select);
  };
  document.getElementById('weirdness').addEventListener('click', handlerWeird, false);
  document.getElementById('normalness').addEventListener('click', handlerNormal, false);
})();
```

```html
<select id="i-am-a-select">
      <option value="weird">weird</option>
      <option value="doubly-so">doubly so</option>
    </select>
    <button id="weirdness">Weirdness</button>
    <button id="normalness">Expected</button>
```

Switching to `Element.querySelectorAll` (and filtering the resultant nodelist) returned the `select` element I needed, so while my specific problem has been fixed, the question remains **why** does this behavior happen and assuming it is documented anywhere, **where** is is documented?

Tested in Chrome (v 65.0.3325.181) and FireFox Quantum (v 58.0.2).

Comment: Why did you use `Array.from` on a single element?

Comment: It's not a weird behavior of `querySelector`, but a weird usage of `Array.from` that is the problem.

Comment: A `select` element is both an Element and a list of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `document.querySelector('#i-am-a-select')` is returning a single [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).

[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) will create an array from an array-like object, or from an iterable object.

An `HTMLSelectElement` is an array-like object, where each item is an option, inside the element.

See this example:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#i-am-a-select');
console.log('First option: ', selectElement[0]);
const select = Array.from(selectElement);
console.log(select);
```

```html
<select id="i-am-a-select">
    <option value="weird">weird</option>
    <option value="doubly-so">doubly so</option>
</select>
```

So, since this element is an "array-like object", `Array.from()` will return an array with its options.

**Careful though:**

Even though you can run trough the `HTMLSelectElement`'s items, it doesn't means this element is an array. To create an array from it, you'll use `Array.from()`.

See this other example:

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#i-am-a-select');
selectElement.forEach(function(){ //will throw an Error
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<select id="i-am-a-select">
    <option value="weird">weird</option>
    <option value="doubly-so">doubly so</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, `Array.from` has nothing to do with this - see my answer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `Array.from()` has everything to do with it.

Comment: The behavior of `selectElement[i]` referencing that element's `<option>`s happens regardless of `Array.from`.

Comment: This is true, but `selectElement` itself is not an `Array`, it's an `HTMLSelectElement`. Try running `selectElement.forEach()` and see it fail. `Array.from()` is the responsible for this behavior.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `Array.from` would fail on other elements that are not array-like or iterable and just result in `[]`, so shouldn't be used on `querySelector`

Comment: @Herohtar I'm trying to find a documentation on why you can run trough the select's options like if they were array items. A normal HTMLElement like a `div` won't allow this, even if it has children.

Comment: @Phiter I'm pretty sure I encountered something talking about it not too long ago, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I just found this question that has some answers refering to this very kind of element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138042/javascript-selecbox-options-to-array

Answer (score -1):

You selected a `select` element:

https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-select-element.html

> select[index]
>
> Returns the item with index index from the list of options. The items are sorted in tree order.

It's nothing to do with `querySelector`, nor really `Array.from` - it's all due to the behavior of `select` elements themselves. `someSelectElement[i]` will return the `i`th option. Convert the element to a plain array, and... the same thing happens, `someSelectElement[i]` will return the `i`th option

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
console.log(select[0]);
console.log(select[1]);
```

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It isn't directly related to being able to select properties using `[]` notation, or even with having numeric indices. Any object allows that notation, but not all objects will be converted using `Array.from`. If your object also has a numeric `.length` or has a `Symbol.iterator`, then it will be converted, even if it has no numeric properties.