# Unable to access options within select element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**The Problem**: I am able to retrieve the HTMLOptionsCollection object from the select element, but unable to get an accurate length or array from it.

For context, I am trying to make an array from the HTMLOptionsCollection object so I can loop through the options to add the selected attribute to one of the option elements. Also, I'm doing this for a chrome extension so I'm not sure if there would be any odd compatibility issues because of that.

Right now, I have this code:

```
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("clients"); // Initially empty

  fillDropdown(); // This does in fact fill the select element with option elements

  console.log(dropdown) // Returns select element
  console.log(dropdown.options); // Returns filled HTMLOptionsCollection object
  console.log(dropdown.options.length); // Returns 0

  // Make an array out of HTMLOptionsCollection object (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138042/javascript-selecbox-options-to-array)
  var arr = Array.apply(null, dropdown.options).map(function(el) { return el.value; });
  console.log(arr); // Returns Array[0]
```

Here are the console.log results:
[image: Console log showcasing the unexpected behavior]
[image: Showcasing the fact that the dropdown.options.length is not accurate at all.]

I did not expect the length to be inaccurate at all and can't figure out why this is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is my fillDropdown() function. It's ultimate goal is to append option elements to the select element. The extra jargon is to prevent options from getting too long word wise.

```
  // Input: None
  // Output: None
  // Proceeds to fill the clients dropdown with clients from local storage
  function fillDropdown() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(function(data) {
      if (typeof data.lastClientName !== "undefined") {
        for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
          // Create an option element to add to the dropdown.
          var clientOption = document.createElement("option");
          // cutoff is an array which holds whole words. This is done to cleanly cut off a name.
          var cutoff = clients[i].split(" ");
          // A clients name may have no more than 4 words to its name.
          if (cutoff.length > 4) {
            cutoff = cutoff[0] + " " + cutoff[1] + " " + cutoff[2] + " " + cutoff[3] + " ...";
            // The full name attribute is used to store the actual name.
            clientOption.setAttribute("fullName", clients[i]);
            // The value and innerHTML are both the same and are user visible.
            clientOption.setAttribute("value", cutoff);
            if (data.lastClientName === cutoff) {
              dropdown.value = clientOption.value;
            }
            clientOption.innerHTML = cutoff;
          }
          else {
            // fullName is added here for consistency
            clientOption.setAttribute("fullName", clients[i]);
            clientOption.setAttribute("value", clients[i]);
            if (data.lastClientName === clients[i]) {
              dropdown.value = cutoff;
            }
            clientOption.innerHTML = clients[i];
          }
          dropdown.appendChild(clientOption);
        }
      }
      else {
        for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
          // Create an option element to add to the dropdown.
          var clientOption = document.createElement("option");
          // cutoff is an array which holds whole words. This is done to cleanly cut off a name.
          var cutoff = clients[i].split(" ");
          // A clients name may have no more than 4 words to its name.
          if (cutoff.length > 4) {
            cutoff = cutoff[0] + " " + cutoff[1] + " " + cutoff[2] + " " + cutoff[3] + " ...";
            // The full name attribute is used to store the actual name.
            clientOption.setAttribute("fullName", clients[i]);
            // The value and innerHTML are both the same and are user visible.
            clientOption.setAttribute("value", cutoff);
            clientOption.innerHTML = cutoff;
          }
          else {
            // fullName is added here for consistency
            clientOption.setAttribute("fullName", clients[i]);
            clientOption.setAttribute("value", clients[i]);
            clientOption.innerHTML = clients[i];
          }
          dropdown.appendChild(clientOption);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Also the only html to be concerned with here is

```
<select name="clients" id="clients"></select>
```

Comment: So what is ` fillDropdown()`? My guess you are making an asynchronous request and you are treating it as synchronous.

Comment: If you create a select by hand with some options and run your console log statements, you get expected results. So I suspect something amiss with your `fillDropdown()` function.

Comment: Its more or less a function that creates option elements, then sets a value attribute for the option element, then appends that option element to the select element. I just tried making fillDropdown() a callback function, but yet the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const newArr = Array.from(dropdown.options);
console.log(newArr.length)
```

You can find other ways to do this here: https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work for me. This is a good shorthand though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I just realized that clients in fillDropdown() was not defined. Clients is supposed to be an array of business names that I would use to actually fill the dropdown. Now I'm curious as to why I didn't get an error for that in my console. I thought any undefined variable would show in the console.

On top of clients not being defined, I also had to make fillDropdown a callback function.

Thank you everyone for helping!