# How can I get the value of a select element with multiple options selected?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

I have a select element on my web page that allows the user to select multiple options. I want to obtain an array with the values ​​of all the options that are currently selected.

I have tried using the selectedOptions property of the select element, but it only gives me the first selected option.

Comment: [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) returns an HTMLCollection of the `option` elements that are selected. From that, you can get a list of the `value` attributes of those `option` elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript selecbox.options to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138042/javascript-selecbox-options-to-array)

Comment: @HereticMonkey that linked  question asks and has answers to how to get an array of all of the options for a select element, irrespective of whether the option is selected.

Comment: If you are having a problem  using the `selectedOptions` property of the select element, please edit the post to show the code you tried. It should work although, as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) it returns an HTMLCollection, not an array.

Comment: @traktor If the OP has a problem replacing `document.querySelectorAll("select option");` or `selectbox.options` with `selectbox.selectedOptions`, they are welcome to [edit] their question to explain that, as are you.

Comment: José, a belated welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help center. @HereticMonkey The post states the problem is with `selectedOptions`. What it lacks is debugging information. for which it has been down-voted.

Answer (score -1):

The selectedOptions property of the select element should give you a list of all the currently selected options, not just the first one.

This property returns an HTMLCollection of option elements that are currently selected in the select element.

Here’s an example of how you can use it to get an array of the values of all selected options:

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById("your-select-element-id");
let selectedOptions = Array.from(selectElement.selectedOptions);
let selectedValues = selectedOptions.map(option => option.value);
```

document.getElementById("your-select-element-id") gets the select element with the specified ID. Use querySelector() or whatever you like instead of getElementById().

Array.from(selectElement.selectedOptions) converts the HTMLCollection of selected options into an array.

selectedOptions.map(option => option.value) creates a new array with the values of all selected options.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <body>
    <select
      multiple
      id="ss"
    >
      <option value="a" selected>American Black Bear</option>
      <option value="b" selected>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
      <option value="c">Brown Bear</option>
    </select>
    <script>
      console.log(
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#select > option[selected]")).map(
          (e) => e.getAttribute("value")
        )
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: `e.value` gets the property `value`, which could be differ from the attribute `value`. Also, this answer differs from the accepted answer of the proposed duplicate only in lacking explanation of the code.